# Shared element transition among fragments that belong to different activities in Android lollipop

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a shared element in a fragment that belongs to one Activity.

I want to make a shared element transition in Android Lollipop with an element that is part of a fragment that belongs to another activity.

Is it possible?

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible.

First, when you detect in your fragment that transition is about to happen, build a array of `Pair<View, String>` which you populate with view and transition name.

For example, if you want to animate from thumbnail image to full width image:

```
  Pair[] pairs = new Pair[1];
  pairs[0] = new Pair(thumbnailImage, "THUMBNAIL_IMAGE");
```

Second, pass that array to fragment's activity so it can initiate the actual transition. (I'm using Otto to pass that event up, you can use usual callbacks if you like).

Then, in your activity, start the second activity. (I created a simple method for doing that)

```
public static void transitionExpand(Activity activity, Intent intent, Pair<View, String>[] sharedElements) {
        ActivityOptionsCompat options =
            ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, sharedElements);

        ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle());
}
```

In your second activity, you can add the fragment in the usual way. Then, in second fragment's `onViewCreated()` method, you can call:

```
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(fullWidthImage, "THUMBNAIL_IMAGE");
```

hope it helps

Comment: It is not working...should I use also addSharedElement (View sharedElement, String name)? In the called activity, I have a fragment with a pager and a fragment in it. Could it be the problem?

Comment: I am trying now with an easier part without the pager involved. If it doesn't work, I will share the code. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, your fragment is embedded inside of ViewPager? I ran into issues with that also and I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Setting android:transitionName="THUMBNAIL_IMAGE" on the shared view in the second fragment's layout also works.

I've also found this solution only works for fragments statically declared in the parent's XML, not dynamically added fragments.

Comment: Works also with dynamically added fragments - thank you!

Comment: Its is not working when return from FragmentB in Activity B to Fragment A in Activity A. @Katharina can you confirm that?

Comment: @extmkv as far as I remember the animation worked in both directions

Comment: I found the problem @Katharina ! 
The transaction should be made before activity::onStart

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: As of [v25.1.1 of the support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#25-1-1), these same methods are in the support Fragments.  Links to the docs: [Fragment.postponeEnterTransition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#postponeEnterTransition()) and [Fragment.startPostponedEnterTransition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#startPostponedEnterTransition())

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

It's possible, even with a dynamically added Fragment in the second Activity.

You just need to tell the second Activity not to run its Transition animations until the shared elements have been laid out and measured.

In the `onCreate` of the second Activity call `postponeEnterTransition()` (or `supportPostponeEnterTransition()` if you're using the Support Library).  Dynamically add your Fragment to this Activity.  At the end of the `onCreateView` method in the Fragment that you're dynamically adding, call `getActivity().startPostponedEnterTransition()`.

This of course assumes you've done everything else required for a shared element transition, but I believe these methods are what you're searching for with your question.

Credit to @alex-lockwood's [blog](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/03/activity-postponed-shared-element-transitions-part3b.html) for showing me the light.